# Calculate $1^{30} + 2^{30} + 3^{30} + \ldots + 17^{30} \mod 31$

Tags: number-theory

Calculate $1^{30} + 2^{30} + 3^{30} + \ldots + 17^{30} \mod 31$

Using Fermat's Theorem:
$$
1^{30} = 1 \mod 31,
$$
(since $31$ is prime).
This implies the above is congruent to $17 \mod 31$

This is correct, right?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your solution: $1^{30} = 1$ (mod $31$), while true, is not what you meant to say (i.e. you need this fact for all the other 30th powers too).  [See the answers below.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

True.  But 1^n=1 mod whatever.  Fermat's Little Theorem says that n^30=1 for all n prime to 31.  So your answer of 17 is correct.